# How can I connect two propane tanks together with a regulator?

Tags: gas, propane, regulator

I just bought a park model home and the large propane tank was removed.
I bought 2 smaller tanks (30lbs each) and an auto change over regulator with two pigtails to attach to the 2 tanks.

What do I need to purchase to connect them all together?

The gas line coming from the ground still has the 1st stage regulator on it. Do I just need to add a hose to attach the 1st stage to the dual auto changeover regulator?

Any advice is appreciated - thanks

Comment: Why not contact the propane dealer and get large tank installed and do it right.

Comment: Why is there a gas line coming from the ground up? Where does it come from? How many propane tanks are involved in your set-up?

Comment: At a minimum, a picture of what you've got, and a drawing of what you want would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect the output of the auto change over regulator to the line coming out of the ground.

I am guessing you got the proper 1st stage auto change over.

houses and travel trailers usually have different setups. I had a travel trailer that had the auto setup it was a single stage.

I have built a few homes with propane and they have 2 regulators normally because the tank needs to be away from the home so the tank pressure is reduced by a first stage sent to the house and then reduced again by a 2nd stage.

If you have the wrong size regulator at the tanks the system won’t work well because of restrictions in the plumbing.